# check_nrpe and non-fixed counter names

Tags: nagios, perfmon, nrpe

For some counters I have noticed Windows convently does provide a stable name for them, for example:

```
\.NET Data Provider for SqlServer(_lm_w3svc_3_root-1-123412341234[6789]\Number of Free Conections
```

Where god knows what 1234 is and 6789 is the PID. These counters don't present any sort of `_Total` instance either. Normally I monitor perfmon counters using check_nrpe from Nagios but am not sure how I might work with these that have dynamic names -- any ideas?